# asp form run at server, does not let inner html button onlick setinterval work

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to get a server side button to do some stuff on the client side (`id="formSrvBtn"`), but for some reason the setInterval functionality does not work as expected (expression to evaluate is not evaluated), i've also tried using a client button instead of the server button (`id="formCltBtn"`) which would also be a valid option but with the same unwanted result...
The only way to make it work is to put the button completely outside of the server side context (`id="cltBtn"`) which is not a valid option in our real life scenario.

Heres is the html for a small aspx confirming all of the above:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function dumb_setInterval() {
            setInterval(function(){alert('dumb setInterval after 5000ms!');}, 5000);    
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <p><asp:ImageButton id="formSrvBtn"
            runat="server" 
            OnClientClick="dumb_setInterval();"
            AlternateText="This server img button's setInterval does not work!"
        >           
        </asp:ImageButton></p>
        <p><button id="formCltBtn"
            onclick="dumb_setInterval();"
        >
            This client button's setInterval does not work!
        </button></p>
    </form>
    <p><button id="cltBtn"
        onclick="dumb_setInterval();"
    >
        This client button's setInterval works!
    </button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Form (`id="form1"`) needs to runat server in our real life scenario, so what i need is to get buttons (`id="formSrvBtn"` or `id="formCltBtn"`) click event firing the setInterval correctly.

Here's the solution rep (for visual studio 2005, sorry...): https://github.com/RASMiranda/setIntervalRunAtServer

And here's the direct link to download the solution: https://github.com/RASMiranda/setIntervalRunAtServer/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the default behaviour of `OnClientClick` on your `ImageButton` is not called, as this will force a postback. You can do this by returning false from your `dumb_setInterval()` method:

```
function dumb_setInterval() {
    setInterval(function(){alert('dumb setInterval after 5000ms!');}, 5000);    
    return false;
}
```

Then adding a return statement to your attribute:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="formSrvBtn"
            runat="server" 
            OnClientClick="return dumb_setInterval();"
```

Comment: @RGragam, Of course! Return on OnClientClick! guess is not just setInterval who's dumb...your 2nd solution works great:
_Or just return false from your dumb_setInterval method:_
/_Don't forget to update your ImageButton OnClientClick if using the return false; method:_. 

Thanks!

Comment: I've done this exact thing myself so many times I've lost count!

Comment: So if you could just delete the first suggestion, it's irrelevant, because the cltBtn works fine but is not a valid workaround for this problem. This will make this clearer for newcomers. Then i will happily mark your response as the answer :D Thanks!